# Rows do not auto-fit height when opening the file in Excel - xlsx generated with excelize

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I am using the golang package excelize (https://github.com/qax-os/excelize) to create an xlsx file programmatically, based on existing xlsx file as a template.

I can't find any support within the Excelize package to make sure that rows will auto-fit to height when opened in Excel. Excel claims to do this automatically unless the row height is specified, which I have not done in any of the affected rows.

Is there a cell-level setting or some other setting that could be blocking this from happening?

Is there a way using Excelize to request/require that the row heights should autosize for specific cells or rows?

Comment: I know nothing abount excelize - but within Excel, if you set `wrapText` to true, auto-height is not longer working. So maybe, if you use `wrapText`, this is the reason.